# Retrieve data for another BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I have a cloud page in one BU. And i need to retrieve data from DE in another sibling BU (and DE is not in the Shared folder).
I wrote this code, but it does not display anything. Can anyone help me with this?

```
try {
        var results = Platform.Function.LookupRows('TestDE','lookupRow','rowValue');
        
        if (results && results.length > 0) {
            Variable.SetValue('@test', 'Data is ok'); //this test var I display on the page
        } {
            Variable.SetValue('@test', 'Error');
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        Write(Stringify(e));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ws proxy for this. Sample Code below:

```
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy(); //creates proxy for SOAP call
prox.setClientId({"ID": mid}); //Set the mid of that BU
var deCustKey = 'DataExtensionTest'; //your DE's CustomerKey / External Key

var cols = ["Field1","Field2","Field3","Field4"];
var filter = {
    Property: "Field1",
    SimpleOperator: "equals",
    Value: 101367
};

var desc = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + deCustKey + "]", cols, filter); 
prox.resetClientIds();
//executes the proxy call
```

Comment: but when i set mid i have this error "MemberID 11111111 does not have access to ClientID"
can you halp me what i do wrong ?

Comment: Are you running the code on the parent BU?

Comment: no in sibling BU

Comment: Can you check if your sibling BU has access to that BU?